# SQL Server "failed to retrieve text" -- how to resolve?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When SQL Server throws permissions errors (or other OS errors), it generally logs something of the form `"Cannot open file {blah}. Operating system error 3 (failed to retrieve text for this message)"`.

It's a simple one: what is it that's stopping SQL Server retrieving the error text? I'm assuming it's a permissions problem somewhere, but I don't know what mechanism SQL uses to translate OS error codes to actual text messages to actual get this working in the first place.

**NOTE:** I'm not asking "how do I fix the initial error" (just incase someone misreads the question) -- this is "how do I get SQL Server to sucessfully translate the OS error number to text so I don't have to keep looking up or remembering what the OS error numbers mean".

This is one of those that there probably *is* an answer out there, but it's drowned out by all the questions asking "what does OS error  mean", and I can't find the right google incantation...

Comment: I don't know what stops MSSQl from retrieveing the error message but, ultimately, it should be calling the OS API FormatMessage. It's possible that a mismatch between the OS language and the SQL server language could cause that. Edit: Also, you can get the error string from the command-line by running "net helpmsg 3"

Comment: Ah ... didn't know about `net helpmsg`. Ta :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons why the [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/ms679351) fails: out-of-memory conditions, a locale issue or a corrupt OS instalation. An OOM would not cause this to happen always, the error message would display properly *sometimes*. A locale mismatch would show this problem consistently, and so would a corrupted OS installation. Given that your SQL error is in what looks like US English, I assume your SQL installation is US English. What language is your OS installation? Does the folder `%SystemRoot%\System32\en-US` exist? How about `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\en-US`, and is the SQL instance a 32 bit installation?

Comment: 32-bit install on a 32-bit box (Windows 7 -- my dev PC). Although I see it on our dev servers as well (64-bit Win 2k8 running 64-bit SQL 2k8). OS is set up for UK locale (I'm right-pondian, sorry :-) ), however I have `en` and `en-US` in System32. I have no SysWOW64 folder. However that its using `FormatMessage` at least gives me something to work with.